# SSRS 2016 : Moving the position of the entire parameter box from top to left

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2016

I want to move the entire parameter panel that defaults to the top in SSRS 2016 to the left of the report. Has anyone done this in the past? I can reorder the individual parameters in the panel but I want to move all these parameters to the left i.e. the entire panel with multiple parameters.

I will be publishing the finalized reports to the report server so the same needs to take affect after publishing.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In native mode the parameter area is always at the top of the report.